# ActiveRecord destroy - no exception

Tags: exception, activerecord

I'm doing a `destroy` via ActiveRecord using a field. However, a record in the database with that field value does not exist. So, given this bit of debugging using `pry`:

```
[1] pry(main)> fieldvalue
=> "17785"
[2] pry(main)> person =  Person.where(:fieldname => fieldvalue.to_i)
=> []
[3] pry(main)> person
=> []
[4] pry(main)> person.destroy_all
=> []
```

...why does it not raise an exception at step 4?

The original bit of code, similarly, silently fails to raise an exception:

> begin
>       Person.where(:fieldname => fieldvalue.to_i).destroy_all
>
> ```
> rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => exception
>   @logger.info("ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception raised. Details: #{exception}")   
> rescue Exception => exception
>   @logger.info("Unknown exception raised. Details: #{exception}")
> else
>   @logger.info("Destroying person with field value: #{fieldvalue}")
> end
> ```

i.e. it just logs the "Destroying..." line each time it's run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`destroy_all` does not raise an exception when executed on an empty set (`[]`) because the method, according to [the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class):

> Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method.

Because your `where` query is returning an empty set, there are no records to instantiate – `destroy` is *never actually* being executed on anything, hence there are no exceptions thrown.

Contrast this to a **hypothetical** situation wherein a set is returned that – for some unlikely reason – contained a `nil` object. The set might look something like this

```
people = Person.where("created_at < ?", Time.now)
#=> [#<Person id:1>, nil, #<Person id:2>] # for demonstration only; would not actually happen

people.destroy_all
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

A `NoMethodError` would be thrown on the second *iteration* of `destroy_all`, since destroy would be executed on `nil`, which does not have a `destroy` method.

One other thought: you may be conflating the [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) ActiveRecord method with the [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method. `where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which effectively operates as an array of objects which match the passed conditions. `find`, in contrast, returns **the first object *itself*_** which match the conditions passed. In the real world example from above, if you're seeking to return *a single object* from your query, it may make more sense to use `find` rather than `where`:

```
people = Person.where(:fieldname => fieldvalue.to_i) # returns a collection of all objects matching the condition
people.class
#=> ActiveRecord::Relation

person = Person.find(:fieldname => fieldvalue.to_i) # returns the FIRST object matching the condition
person.class
#=> Person
```